# How to cope with the performance of generating signed URLs for accessing private content via CloudFront?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

A common use case of AWS S3 and CloudFront is serving private content. The common solution is using signed CloudFront URLs to access private files stored using S3.

However, the generation of these URLs comes with a cost: computing the RSA signature of any given URL using a private key. For Python (or `boto`, AWS's Python SDK), the `rsa` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa) library is used for this task. On my late 2014 MBP, it takes about ~25ms per computation with a 2048-bit key.

This cost potentially impacts the scalability of an application that uses this approach for authorizing access to private content via CloudFront. Imagine multiple clients request for access to multiple files frequently at 25~30ms/req.

It seems to me that not much can be improve on the signature computation itself, though the `rsa` library mentioned above was last updated almost 1.5 years ago. I wonder if there are other techniques or designs that may optimize the performance of this process to achieve higher scalability. Or do we simply have to throw in more hardware and try to solve it in a brute force way?

One optimization can be making the API endpoint accept multiple file signings per request and return the signed URLs in bulk rather than dealing with them individually in separate requests, but the total time necessary for computing all those signatures is still there.

Comment: Thinking about this today, myself. Are you measuring literally just the generation of the signature, or tasks like loading the key, preparing the policy, etc.?

Comment: @abathur, I measured both the time for generating the signature (RSA) only (key is already cached on the server side, and policy is already configured) and the time for the whole request handling (incl. some custom logic). So on my machine, it was ~25ms for signature generation, and ~30ms for processing the whole request.

Comment: @MLister: could you provide a code chunk showing the lines you are using for computing the RSA signature of an example URL?

Comment: @Peque, that is a single line using the provided function in `boto`, i.e. `create_signed_url` function on a CloudFront distribution object: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html#boto.cloudfront.distribution.Distribution.create_signed_url. In addition, the distribution object is create once at start-up and cached on the server instead of creating afresh on each request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Use Signed Cookies**

When I use CloudFront with many private URLs, I prefer to use [Signed Cookies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) when all the [restrictions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html) are met. This does not speed up the generation of signed cookies but it reduces the number of signing requests to be one per user until they expire.

**Tuning RSA Signature Generation**

I can imagine you may have requirements which render signed cookies as an invalid option. In that case I tried to speed up the signing by comparing the [RSA](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa) module used with boto and [cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography). Two additional alternative options are [m2crypto](https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto) and [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) but for this example I will use cryptography.

In order to test performance of signing URLs with different modules I reduced the method [_sign_string](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/f929e0c97df03685d8d02181f9df7b693592efaa/boto/cloudfront/distribution.py#L650) to remove any logic except the signing of a string then created a new `Distribution` class. Then I took the private key and example URL from [boto tests](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/2d7796a625f9596cbadb7d00c0198e5ed84631ed/tests/unit/cloudfront/test_signed_urls.py#L14) to test with.

The results show that cryptography is quicker but still requires close to 1ms per signing request. These results are skewed higher by iPython's use of scoped variables in timing.

```
timeit -n10000 rsa_distribution.create_signed_url(url, message, expire_time)
10000 loops, best of 3: 6.01 ms per loop

timeit -n10000 cryptography_distribution.create_signed_url(url, message, expire_time)
10000 loops, best of 3: 644 µs per loop
```

The full script:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

import rsa

from boto.cloudfront.distribution import Distribution

from textwrap import dedent

# The private key provided in the Boto tests
pk_key = dedent("""
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIICXQIBAAKBgQDA7ki9gI/lRygIoOjV1yymgx6FYFlzJ+z1ATMaLo57nL57AavW
    hb68HYY8EA0GJU9xQdMVaHBogF3eiCWYXSUZCWM/+M5+ZcdQraRRScucmn6g4EvY
    2K4W2pxbqH8vmUikPxir41EeBPLjMOzKvbzzQy9e/zzIQVREKSp/7y1mywIDAQAB
    AoGABc7mp7XYHynuPZxChjWNJZIq+A73gm0ASDv6At7F8Vi9r0xUlQe/v0AQS3yc
    N8QlyR4XMbzMLYk3yjxFDXo4ZKQtOGzLGteCU2srANiLv26/imXA8FVidZftTAtL
    viWQZBVPTeYIA69ATUYPEq0a5u5wjGyUOij9OWyuy01mbPkCQQDluYoNpPOekQ0Z
    WrPgJ5rxc8f6zG37ZVoDBiexqtVShIF5W3xYuWhW5kYb0hliYfkq15cS7t9m95h3
    1QJf/xI/AkEA1v9l/WN1a1N3rOK4VGoCokx7kR2SyTMSbZgF9IWJNOugR/WZw7HT
    njipO3c9dy1Ms9pUKwUF46d7049ck8HwdQJARgrSKuLWXMyBH+/l1Dx/I4tXuAJI
    rlPyo+VmiOc7b5NzHptkSHEPfR9s1OK0VqjknclqCJ3Ig86OMEtEFBzjZQJBAKYz
    470hcPkaGk7tKYAgP48FvxRsnzeooptURW5E+M+PQ2W9iDPPOX9739+Xi02hGEWF
    B0IGbQoTRFdE4VVcPK0CQQCeS84lODlC0Y2BZv2JxW3Osv/WkUQ4dslfAQl1T303
    7uwwr7XTroMv8dIFQIPreoPhRKmd/SbJzbiKfS/4QDhU
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----""")

# Initializing keys in a global context
cryptography_private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    pk_key,
    password=None,
    backend=default_backend())


# Instantiate a signer object using PKCS 1v 15, this is not recommended but required for Amazon
def sign_with_cryptography(message):
    signer = cryptography_private_key.signer(
        padding.PKCS1v15(),
        hashes.SHA1())

    signer.update(message)
    return signer.finalize()


# Initializing the key in a global context
rsa_private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(pk_key)


def sign_with_rsa(message):
    signature = rsa.sign(str(message), rsa_private_key, 'SHA-1')

    return signature


# All this information comes from the Boto tests.
url = "http://d604721fxaaqy9.cloudfront.net/horizon.jpg?large=yes&license=yes"
expected_url = "http://d604721fxaaqy9.cloudfront.net/horizon.jpg?large=yes&license=yes&Expires=1258237200&Signature=Nql641NHEUkUaXQHZINK1FZ~SYeUSoBJMxjdgqrzIdzV2gyEXPDNv0pYdWJkflDKJ3xIu7lbwRpSkG98NBlgPi4ZJpRRnVX4kXAJK6tdNx6FucDB7OVqzcxkxHsGFd8VCG1BkC-Afh9~lOCMIYHIaiOB6~5jt9w2EOwi6sIIqrg_&Key-Pair-Id=PK123456789754"
message = "PK123456789754"
expire_time = 1258237200


class CryptographyDistribution(Distribution):
    def _sign_string(
            self,
            message,
            private_key_file=None,
            private_key_string=None):
        return sign_with_cryptography(message)


class RSADistribution(Distribution):
    def _sign_string(
            self,
            message,
            private_key_file=None,
            private_key_string=None):
        return sign_with_rsa(message)


cryptography_distribution = CryptographyDistribution()
rsa_distribution = RSADistribution()

cryptography_url = cryptography_distribution.create_signed_url(
    url,
    message,
    expire_time)

rsa_url = rsa_distribution.create_signed_url(
    url,
    message,
    expire_time)

assert cryptography_url == rsa_url == expected_url, "URLs do not match"
```

**Conclusion**

Although the cryptography module performs better in this test, I recommend trying to find a way to utilize signed cookies but I hope this information is useful.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking into the options and didn't have enough time last night to test a `cryptography` version. Figured I'd add some of my timing figures in case they help someone later: ~1550µs (1.5ms) for the `cryptography` signing method, ~37ms for the `rsa` signing method (both compared with ~30µs for the existing s3 signing method.)

Comment: @erik-e thanks for the answer. I looked into the signed cookies approach a bit, but it seems that `boto` does not support it currently. Did you roll your own?

Comment: Yes, but used the same `_sign_string` method from `boto`. Since timing wasn't as important I didn't change from the default `rsa` implementation in `boto`.

Comment: Just a note that the key used in this answer is not 2048-bit (recommended these days) in length, thus the speed achieved will be considerably faster than if we use a 2048-bit key. When using a 2048-bit key, the implementation using the `cryptography` library consumes about 2.5 ms per signature during benchmarking.

Comment: Great point, that accounts for the skew in my performance metrics as well.

Answer (score 5):

## Briefly

Consider whether you can (in addition to using `python-cryptography`, per @erik-e) use a shorter key length (and probably [change keys more frequently](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/94617/67656)), given the particulars of your use case. While I can sign with the 2048-bit key AWS generated in ~1550µs, it only takes ~307µs at 1028 bits, ~184µs at 768 bits, and ~113µs at 512 bits.

## Explanation

After looking into this for a bit, I'm going to go in another direction and build off of the (already great) answer @erik-e gave. I should mention before I get into it that I don't know how *acceptable* this idea is; I am just reporting on the performance impact it has (see the end of the post for a question I asked on the security SE seeking input on this).

I was collecting timings on signing with `cryptography` as @erik-e suggests, and because of the still large performance gulf between it and our existing signing method for S3, I decided to profile the code to see if it looked like there might be anything obvious chewing up time:

```
>>> cProfile.runctx('[sign_url_cloudfront2("...") for x in range(0,100)]', globals(), locals(), sort="time")
         9403 function calls in 0.218 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      200    0.161    0.001    0.161    0.001 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_sign}
      100    0.006    0.000    0.186    0.002 rsa.py:214(_finalize_pkey_ctx)
     1200    0.004    0.000    0.008    0.000 {isinstance}
      400    0.004    0.000    0.007    0.000 api.py:212(new)
      100    0.003    0.000    0.218    0.002 views.py:888(sign_url_cloudfront2)
      300    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 abc.py:128(__instancecheck__)
      100    0.002    0.000    0.008    0.000 hashes.py:53(finalize)
      200    0.002    0.000    0.005    0.000 gc_weakref.py:10(build)
      100    0.002    0.000    0.007    0.000 hashes.py:15(__init__)
      100    0.002    0.000    0.018    0.000 rsa.py:151(__init__)
      100    0.002    0.000    0.014    0.000 hashes.py:68(__init__)
      200    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 gc_weakref.py:14(remove)
      200    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 api.py:239(cast)
      100    0.002    0.000    0.190    0.002 rsa.py:207(finalize)
      200    0.001    0.000    0.007    0.000 api.py:325(gc)
      500    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {getattr}
      400    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {_cffi_backend.newp}
      400    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 api.py:150(_typeof)
      200    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 api.py:266(buffer)
      200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 utils.py:18(<lambda>)
      300    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 _weakrefset.py:68(__contains__)
      200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {_cffi_backend.buffer}
      100    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 hashes.py:49(update)
      100    0.001    0.000    0.010    0.000 hashes.py:102(finalize)
      100    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 hashes.py:88(update)
      200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
      100    0.001    0.000    0.019    0.000 rsa.py:528(signer)
      300    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {len}
      100    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 base64.py:42(b64encode)
      100    0.001    0.000    0.008    0.000 backend.py:148(create_hash_ctx)
      200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {_cffi_backend.cast}
      200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_get_digestbyname}
      100    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
      100    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 rsa.py:204(update)
      200    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'dict' objects}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {binascii.b2a_base64}
      200    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_cffi_backend.typeof}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_DigestUpdate}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.218    0.218 <string>:1(<module>)
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_DigestInit_ex}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_CTX_new}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_CTX_free}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_DigestFinal_ex}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_MD_CTX_create}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_size}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'translate' of 'str' objects}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_sign_init}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_MD_CTX_destroy}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

While there might be some small savings lurking inside `signer`, the vast majority of the time is spent inside of the finalize() call, and almost all of that time is spent inside the actual sign call to openssl. While this was a little disappointing, it was a clear indicator that I should look to the actual signing process for savings.

I was just using the 2048-bit key CloudFront generated for us, so I decided to see what impact a smaller key would have on performance. I re-ran the profile using the shorter key:

```
>>> cProfile.runctx('[sign_url_cloudfront2("...") for x in range(0,100)]', globals(), locals(), sort="time")
        9203 function calls in 0.063 seconds

  Ordered by: internal time

  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     100    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_sign}
     400    0.005    0.000    0.008    0.000 api.py:212(new)
     100    0.004    0.000    0.033    0.000 rsa.py:214(_finalize_pkey_ctx)
    1200    0.004    0.000    0.008    0.000 {isinstance}
     100    0.003    0.000    0.063    0.001 views.py:897(sign_url_cloudfront2)
     300    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 abc.py:128(__instancecheck__)
     100    0.002    0.000    0.008    0.000 hashes.py:53(finalize)
     200    0.002    0.000    0.005    0.000 gc_weakref.py:10(build)
     100    0.002    0.000    0.007    0.000 hashes.py:15(__init__)
     100    0.002    0.000    0.014    0.000 hashes.py:68(__init__)
     100    0.002    0.000    0.018    0.000 rsa.py:151(__init__)
     200    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 gc_weakref.py:14(remove)
     100    0.001    0.000    0.036    0.000 rsa.py:207(finalize)
     200    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 api.py:239(cast)
     200    0.001    0.000    0.006    0.000 api.py:325(gc)
     500    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {getattr}
     200    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 api.py:266(buffer)
     400    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {_cffi_backend.newp}
     400    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 api.py:150(_typeof)
     100    0.001    0.000    0.010    0.000 hashes.py:102(finalize)
     200    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 utils.py:18(<lambda>)
     300    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 _weakrefset.py:68(__contains__)
     100    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 hashes.py:88(update)
     100    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 hashes.py:49(update)
     200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
     200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_get_digestbyname}
     100    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 base64.py:42(b64encode)
     100    0.001    0.000    0.008    0.000 backend.py:148(create_hash_ctx)
     100    0.001    0.000    0.019    0.000 rsa.py:520(signer)
     200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {_cffi_backend.buffer}
     200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'dict' objects}
     200    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {_cffi_backend.cast}
     100    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
     100    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {time.time}
     100    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 rsa.py:204(update)
     200    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
     200    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_cffi_backend.typeof}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {binascii.b2a_base64}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'translate' of 'str' objects}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.063    0.063 <string>:1(<module>)
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_DigestUpdate}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_CTX_new}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_DigestInit_ex}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_MD_CTX_destroy}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_DigestFinal_ex}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_MD_CTX_create}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_sign_init}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_size}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_CTX_free}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md}
     100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

As mentioned in my comment on erik-e's answer, the runtime I saw for our full signing method using the 2048-bit key with the `cryptography` module was ~1550µs. Repeating this same test with the 512-bit key brings the runtime down to about ~113µs (a stone's-throw from the ~30µs of our S3 signing method).

This result seems meaningful, but it hinges on [how acceptable it is to use a shorter key for your purpose](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/94617/67656). I was able to find a comment from March on a Mozilla issue report [suggesting a 512-bit key could be broken for $75 in 8 hours on EC2](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138554#c7).

Comment: Do you know whether the `cryptography` module's moduli have 2 or [3 prime factors](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2006/cacr2006-16.pdf)? ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I won't pretend to know; what I've read of their code so far suggests the answer will be: whatever openssl uses. If I *am* following, I think that means the answer is 2.

Comment: the related question on security exchange is very helpful, and the answer to that question argues that using a 1024-bit private key (with key rotation) is gives good balance between performance and security.